# Elasticsearch cross_field all terms must be present in at least on field

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I want to build an Elasticsearch query where I query multiple fields and all fields must appear in at least one field. I use `multi_match` query with `cross_field`. [Elascticsearch documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields)

For example :

My search are over User object like :

```
{ firstname: '...', lastname: '...', email: '...' }
```

We have 2 users :

```
{
  firstname: 'Delphine',
  lastname: 'Dorémi',
  email: 'tyrell@interne.fr'
}

{
  firstname: 'Philippe',
  lastname: 'Mifasol',
  email: 'roybatty@interne.com'
}
```

Query : "Rachel Mifasol"

**The result I want :** no result (because "Rachel" is missing in "Philippe" user object)

**The result that Elasticsearch actually give to me :** "Philippe" (I suppose because "Mifasol" match...)

Here my Elasticsearch query:

```
query: {
  multi_match: {
    query: 'Rachel Mifasol',
    type: 'cross_fields',
    fields: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'emails'],
    operator: 'and'
  }
}
```

And here my analyser and mappings :

```
settings: {
  analysis: {
    filter: {
      nGram_filter: {
        type: 'nGram',
          min_gram: 2,
          max_gram: 20,
          token_chars: [
          'letter',
          'digit',
          'punctuation',
          'symbol'
        ]
      }
    },
    analyzer: {
      nGram_analyzer: {
        type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'whitespace',
          filter: [
          'lowercase',
          'asciifolding',
          'nGram_filter'
        ]
      },
      whitespace_analyzer: {
        type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'whitespace',
          filter: [
          'lowercase',
          'asciifolding'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
mappings: {
  users: {
    properties: {
      firstname: {
        type: 'string',
          index_analyzer: 'nGram_analyzer',
          search_analyzer: 'whitespace_analyzer',
          fields: {
          sort: {
            type: 'string',
            index: 'not_analyzed'
          }
        }
      },
      lastname: {
        type: 'string',
          index_analyzer: 'nGram_analyzer',
          search_analyzer: 'whitespace_analyzer'
      },
      emails: {
        type: 'string',
          index_analyzer: 'nGram_analyzer',
          search_analyzer: 'whitespace_analyzer'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting zero results with that query?

Comment: My app do this query (an array of word) :

    query: {
      multi_match: {
        query: [ 'Rachel', 'Mifasol' ],
        type: 'cross_fields',
        fields: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'emails'],
        operator: 'and'
      }
    }

That why I had results...

So my question is a mistake. Sorry.

Comment: have you figured out yet?

Comment: My question was a mistake. The query I sent to ES was ['Rachel', 'Mifasol'] instead of 'Rachel Mifasol'.